# JpaSystemException when using composite key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am building a spring boot application and I am stuck with the `JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property` error. Let me give you some details about the project.

First of all, I have the following db schema

```
describe airports;

+--------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| airport_id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| airport_name             | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

describe flights;

+------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| flight_from_airport_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| flight_to_airport_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| flight_type            | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Basically, table flights is used to store data for flights from one airport to another.

I have two entities; airport and flight as follows:

`Airport.java`

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "airports")
public class Airport {
    @Id
    @Column(name="airport_id")
    private int airportId;
    
    @Column(name="airport_name")
    private String airportName;
    
    //Getters and Setters

    public Airport(int airportId, String airportName) {
        this.airportId = airportId;
        this.airportName = airportName;
    }
}
```

`Flight.java`

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MapsId;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "flights")
public class Flight {
    
    @EmbeddedId
    FlightPrimaryKey flightPrimaryKey;

    @MapsId("fromAirport")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "flightFromAirportId")
    private Airport fromAirport;

    @MapsId("toAirport")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "flightToAirportId")
    private Airport toAirport;

    @Column(name="flight_type")
    private int flightType;

    //Getters and Setters

    public Flight(FlightPrimaryKey flightPrimaryKey, int flightType) {
        this.flightPrimaryKey = flightPrimaryKey;
        this.flightType = flightType;
    }
}
```

Because I want a composite key for the class Flight, I have an Id class.

`FlightId.java`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class FlightId implements Serializable {
        
    @Column(name = "flight_from_airport_id")
    private int fromAirport;

    @Column(name = "flight_to_airport_id")
    private int toAirport;

    // Getters and Setters, hashcode, equals

    public TransferPrimaryKey(int fromAirport, int toAirport) {
        this.fromAirport = fromAirport;
        this.toAirport = toAirport;
    }
}
```

Then I have a JPA repository

`FlightRepository.java`

```
public interface FlightRepository extends JpaRepository<Flight, FlightId>{}
```

And to test the above I use the following code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FlightTest {

    @Autowired
    private AiportRepository airportRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FlightRepository flightRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldStoreAFlight() {
        Airport fromAirport = airportRepository.save(new Airport(1, "LAX");
        Airport toAirport = airportRepository.save(new Airport(2, "JFK")
        FlightId flightId = new FlightId(fromAirport.getId(), toAirport.getId());
        Flight flight = flightRepository.save(new Flight(flightId, 1));
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the JpaSystemException. I also cannot understand why the error says about one-to-one property. I have only defined a many-to-one property. Clearly I am missing something.

Comment: The error tells you the problem - you left your flight references (toAirport, fromAirport) null. MapsId tells JPA to use the values from the references to set the foreign key (which is also the primary key), so there is no need to pull out the fromAiport.getId value yourself. This allows you to create a fromAirport, toAirport and flight and save it all in the same transaction, letting JPA set the ids for you in the entire object graph.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think I get it. You mean that I should initialise the fromAirport and toAirport from my Flight object? Something like `flight.setAirport(fromAirport)` ?

Comment: Yes, you got it. MapsId("fromAirport") tells JPA that the embedded FlightId.fromAirport value must come from this referenced Airport, but you've left the fromAirport null. Setting it allows JPA to pull its id which is then used to set both the foreign key column, and the embedded  FlightId.fromAirport value. There is no need to create a FlightId instance with the fromAirport.getId()/toAirport.getId() values - the new Flight just needs an empty FlightId instance and JPA will set them for you.

Comment: Apparently I still don't get it code-wise :)
I added `flight.setAirport(fromAirport)` before saving the new flight object but I still get the same error. Maybe because I use the same variable names in different classes I am getting confused when reading your answer. So, the problem is that fromFlight object of class Flight is null. Right? If so, why isn't the above snippet solving the error?

Comment: If you've done the same for both fromAirport and toAirport references in the Airport - show the code and the exception stack trace. Error says one of them is null, so you might use a debugger to verify you have indeed used non-null references in both as I have no idea what you are setting with a setAirport method

Comment: OMG! I followed your steps but then I was saving the wrong thing. I was saving `flight = flightRepository.save(new Flight(flightId, 1));` instead of `flight = flightRepository.save(flight);`.  Thank you for your time! You were correct the whole time but my brain was fried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution should be to set your references:

```
public void shouldStoreAFlight() {
  Airport fromAirport = airportRepository.save(new Airport(1, "LAX");
  Airport toAirport = airportRepository.save(new Airport(2, "JFK")
  FlightId flightId = new FlightId(fromAirport.getId(), toAirport.getId());
  Flight flight  = new Flight(flightId, 1);
  flight.setFromAirport(fromAirport);
  flight.setToAirport(toAirport);
  flight = flightRepository.save(flight);
}
```

There should be no need to set the values in FlightId with the above code, but I left it to match your constructors, and because you have them set to *int* instead of an Integer that allows nulls.